# Is it necessary to update the channel before rebuild switch?

Tags: nixos

https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/#sec-ad-hoc-packages says

> Packages come from the NixOS channel. You typically upgrade a package
> by updating to the latest version of the NixOS channel:
>
> ```
> $ nix-channel --update nixos
> ```
>
> and then running `nix-env -i` again. Other packages in the profile are
> not affected; this is the crucial difference with the declarative
> style of package management, where **running `nixos-rebuild switch`
> causes all packages to be updated to their current versions in the
> NixOS channel.**

On NixOS, before running

```
sudo nixos-rebuild switch
```

is it necessary to update the channel by

```
nix-channel update nixos
```

?

Or will the switch command  do the channel update by itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a channel and rebuild, use the `--upgrade` option described in the `nixos-rebuild` manage

[Manpages](https://www.mankier.com/8/nixos-rebuild)